# Have pyodbc return a simple (scalar) value for a query that only returns one item

Tags: python, pyodbc

I am having an issue when I select data from the SQL database through pyodbc where I end up with this type of result.

> [(55.0, )]

I want the pure number (no "[" or "(" so I later can insert it into a different table after calculating new stuff with it. I am sure it's trivial but I just haven't been able to figure out how. Below is the code I am using:

```
rows = conn.execute("SELECT price from PG").fetchall()
print(rows[:1])
```

Comment: But here you fetch all records, and you are only printing the first one?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have `[(55.0, )]` because you have a list of rows (containing a single row in this example), and each row is a tuple (with a single element, since you just selected `price`). You can do

```
singlerow = rows[0]
price, = singlerow
```

However, fetching all rows to select just one seems weird, you should probably re-think your query.

Answer (score 17):

Note for future readers: The pyodbc Cursor object has a [fetchval](https://github.com/mkleehammer/pyodbc/wiki/Features-beyond-the-DB-API#fetchval) method:

> The fetchval() convenience method returns the first column of the first row if there are results, otherwise it returns None.

(It is similar to the .NET `ExecuteScalar()` method.)

So instead of doing something like

```python
row_count = crsr.execute("SELECT COUNT(*) FROM TableName").fetchone()[0]
```

we can just do

```python
row_count = crsr.execute("SELECT COUNT(*) FROM TableName").fetchval()
```

It has the added advantage of returning `None` (instead of throwing an exception) if the query returns no rows.

Comment: Sadly, `fetchval` is pyodbc-specific and [pypyodbc doesn't have it](https://github.com/jiangwen365/pypyodbc/search?q=fetchval&unscoped_q=fetchval).

Comment: @Nickolay I believe the OP only asked for pyodbc.